# Angular 4 Redirecting on ngOnInit

Tags: angular, angular4-router

I am working in the Angular 4 application. I wants to authorize a user before loading the app.component(even this app.component should not be initialized) and will redirects to unauthorized page if not authorized by checking API, and will redirect to the actual page when user is valid.

This the way what I have done. I am not redirecting the app component page if user is valid and not redirecting to unauthorized page.

*AuthorizationComponent.ts*

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from "@angular/router";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-authorization',
  templateUrl: './authorization.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./authorization.component.css']
})
export class AuthorizationComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    alert('auth component and redireting to /app')
    // API Call goes here,
    If(UserIsInValid)
       this.router.navigate['/UnAuthorized']
    else
      this.router.navigate['/app']

  }

  ngOnDestroy()
  {
    alert('auth destroy')
  }

  ngAfterViewInit()
  {
    alert('auth after init')        
  }

}
```

*AuthorizationComponent.html*

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

*app.component.ts*

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

constructor(private _router: Router) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {}
  }
```

*app.component.html*

```
 <nav>
      <a routerLink="/component-one">Component One</a>
      <a routerLink="/component-two">Component Two</a>
    </nav>

    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

I have a `app.routing.ts`

```
 import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { Routes, RouterModule } from "@angular/router";
import { FirstComponent } from './FirstComponent';
import { SecondComponent } from './SecondComponent';
import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";
 import { ErrorComponent } from "./error.component";
import { AuthorizationComponent } from "./shared/authorization/authorization.component";

const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: AuthorizationComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
    {
        path: 'app',component:AppComponent,
        children: [
            {path:'', redirectTo:'First', pathMatch: 'full'},
            {path:'First', component: FirstComponent},
            {path:'Second', component: SecondComponent}
            //{path:'', component: FirstComponent}
        ]
    },

    { path: 'NotFound', component: ErrorComponent },
    { path: 'Error', component: ErrorComponent },
    { path: 'UnAuthorized', component: ErrorComponent },
    { path: '**', redirectTo: 'NotFound' }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }

export const routingComponents = [FirstComponent, SecondComponent];
```

*app.module.ts*

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { routingComponents, AppRoutingModule } from './app.routing';
import { AuthorizationComponent } from './shared/authorization/authorization.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    routingComponents,
    AuthorizationComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule    
  ],
  providers: [

  ],
  bootstrap: [AuthorizationComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should move your check into a [CanActivate Guard](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate)

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(private router: Router){}

    canActivate(): boolean {
        if(UserIsInValid){
            // user is invalid. redirect to unauthorized route
            this.router.navigate['/UnAuthorized'];
            return;
        } else {
            // user is valid, continue to route
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can attach the guard to any route that needs to be protected

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'app',component:AppComponent,
        canActivate: [ AuthGuard ],
        children: [
            {path:'', redirectTo:'First', pathMatch: 'full'},
            {path:'First', component: FirstComponent},
            {path:'Second', component: SecondComponent}
        ]
    }
]
```